# Google App Engine Rails Postgres won't connect to Cloud SQL database: No such file or directory

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, google-app-engine, google-cloud-sql

I have a Rails app that should be hosted via Google Cloud App Engine. It has a Postgres database setup. I followed this tutorial: https://cloud.google.com/ruby/rails/using-cloudsql-postgres

I added all my configurations in app.yaml:

```
entrypoint: bundle exec rackup --port $PORT
env: flex
runtime: ruby

env_variables:
  SECRET_KEY_BASE: [SECRET_KEY]

beta_settings:
  cloud_sql_instances: [INSTANCE]
```

and database.yml:

```
production:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000
  username: postgres
  password: [DB_PASSWORD]
  database: [DB_DATABASE]
  host: /cloudsql/[INSTANCE]
```

The Cloud SQL instance is setup correctly as I can connect to it using Cloud SQL proxy: https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/connect-admin-proxy

After deployment to App Engine and trying to migrate it gives me the follwoing error:

```
PG::ConnectionBad: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
    Is the server running locally and accepting
    connections on Unix domain socket "/cloudsql/[INSTANCE]/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

This also happens with a running proxy locally and trying to

```
RAILS_ENV=production rake db:create rake db:migrate
```

I see that /cloudsql folder is missing when I SSH into the App Engine's VM. I double-checked, access rights should be there and Cloud SQL API and Cloud SQL Admin API are enabled. I also noticed that when SSHing into the App Engine's VMs (apparently there are two, I tried both of them) and running ls the directories are completely empty. The deployment worked though as I can access the app but not the controller that require DB connection.

Comment: is you [INSTANCE] following this pattern
```[PROJECT]:[REGION]:[INSTANCE NAME] ```? for example tetsingfakeproject:us-central1:testdatabase

Comment: @JAHDZP Yes, I followed the tutorial exactly step by step...

Comment: I found another Google tutorial better explained, please check it in order to know if an step is missing in the other tutorial

https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/cloud-ruby-on-rails-cloud-sql-postgres-ruby/index.html?index=..%2F..index#0

Answer (score 0):

I followed this old but better explained [GCP tutorial](https://kiosk-dot-codelabs-site.appspot.com/codelabs/cloud-ruby-on-rails-cloud-sql-postgres-ruby/index.html?index=..%2F..index#4)(this tutorial is designed to use cloud shell) and I realized that is mandatory to have running Cloud SQL Proxy on your local env (in another terminal or background)

Cloud sql proxy will create the unix socket file

`Listening on /cloudsql/tetsingfakeproject:us-central1:testdatabase ce/.s.PGSQL.5432 for tetsingfakeproject:us-central1:testdatabase`

This in order to perform the migrations, and you can pass that step on the local environment.

**Notes about using this [tutorial](https://kiosk-dot-codelabs-site.appspot.com/codelabs/cloud-ruby-on-rails-cloud-sql-postgres-ruby/index.html?index=..%2F..index#4)**

I followed all steps of the old tutorial with some alternative steps

In the step 3, I ran the newest command to enable the SQL admin api:

`gcloud service enable sqladmin.googleapis.com`

In the step 10, I installed the pg and appengine packages using these commands instead modifying the file "Gemfile"

```
bundle add pg
bundle add appengine
```

If the deploy time of this ruby app takes more than 10 minutes, please run this command

`gcloud config set app/cloud_build_timeout 3600s`

And run `gcloud app deploy` again.

following this tutorial I can get a functional App Engine Service using ruby + postgresql, I had a lot of issues using the other tutorial

Comment: Same error with this tutorial...Proxy is running locally but no chance

Is there a way to access the app in Cloud Shell and run the production migrations there after deployment?

Comment: the second tutorial is designed to run on cloud shell i forgot mentioned this detail